# HotChocolate Batching error: "The specified directive `export` is not supported by the current schema."

Tags: hotchocolate

Following the documentation [on Batching with @export](https://hotchocolate.io/docs/batching#export-directive) this tag is not allowed for my server. How can I add the directive so batching is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The export directive has to be registered with the schema builder.

```cs
SchemaBuilder.New()
    .AddType<ExportDirectiveType>()
    ...
    .Create();
```

This detail is missing in the documentation. I will update the documentation and add this detail.

The directive is in the `HotChocolate.Execution.Batching` namespace.